# Default built-in editors for the PropertyGrid control

Tags: c#, editor, propertygrid

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. What default editors/converters are building into 3.5 Framework PropertyGrid control. Otherwise what object types can I throw at it and it be able to reliably show and edit? I've found a lot of tutorials on using custom editors (which I may do at some point). But right now in my program I'm allowing the user to create their own custom properties and I want to know what object types I should allow assuming they will be editing them in a PropertyGrid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at classes that derive from [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx) (in the [`System.Drawing.Design` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.aspx)).  These types will be passed as parameters to the [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) (in the [`System.ComponentModel` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z82ykwhb.aspx)).

You can also look at the metadata for the type to see where the `EditorAttribute` is applied.  However, **do not** use reflection here, as that is not what the [`PropertyGrid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) uses.

Rather use the [`TypeDescriptor` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) to get property descriptors for the properties on the type (call the static [`GetProperties` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2k1x8zt.aspx)).  Then, with the [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx) instance, call the [`GetEditor` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.geteditor.aspx) to get an instance of the editor for that property.

Answer (score 8):

Bear in mind that there some non-public classes.

```
System.Object
  System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor
    System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor
      System.ComponentModel.Design.ArrayEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.CollectionEditorBase
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.WizardStepCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.EmbeddedMailObjectCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.HotSpotCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.ListItemsCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.MenuItemStyleCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.RoleGroupCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.StyleCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.SubMenuStyleCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.TableCellsCollectionEditor
      System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.TableRowsCollectionEditor
    System.ComponentModel.Design.BinaryEditor
    System.ComponentModel.Design.DateTimeEditor
    System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor
    System.ComponentModel.Design.ObjectSelectorEditor
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.AnchorEditor
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.BorderSidesEditor
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.DockEditor
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor
    System.Windows.Forms.Design.ShortcutKeysEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.ConnectionStringEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.DataBindingCollectionEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.ExpressionsCollectionEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.XmlFileEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.DataGridColumnCollectionEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.DataControlFieldTypeEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.MenuBindingsEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.MenuItemCollectionEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.ParameterCollectionEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.RegexTypeEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.TreeNodeCollectionEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.TreeViewBindingsEditor
    System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.DataPagerFieldTypeEditor
    System.Messaging.Design.QueuePathEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.ImageEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.ColorEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.ContentAlignmentEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.CursorEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.FontEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.FontNameEditor
    System.Drawing.Design.IconEditor
    System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Design.TypeBrowserEditor
    System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Design.BindUITypeEditor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually throw any object at the PropertyGrid. It will do a lot of things automatically. You only need to create custom UI type editors if you want to have a special edit experience, which is not natively provided. And even in that case you do it per property and not for a whole object.

Comment: But what are all the things it will do automaticly? Right now I don't want to deal with custom editors. I've tried various numbers, string, bool, and DateTime and they all either work or have built in editors. I was hoping there was a list somewhere of all the types that can be edited by default.

Comment: You can look at the inheritance hierarchy of your property types if they have a UITypeEditor attached as an attribute or not. By default the property grid needs either an editor or a type converter to get to/from string.

Answer (score 1):

The PropertyGrid uses TypeConverters and there are TypeConverters for every primitive type (as well as collections of primitive types).

As long as you're using one of the primitive types or a collection of primitive types the property grid should be able to take care of providing an editing UI.

Answer (score 1):

Besides UITypeEditors, the PropertyGrid is able to display any object with a TypeConverter that returns true for CanConvertFrom(String).  You can implement your own TypeConverters for specific object types in order to accomplish this.